# Spring Boot 2.1.0 and Flyway 4.2.0 - Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I need to use **Flyway 4.2.0** in my project because of old Oracle DB. With Spring Boot 2.1.0 the Flyway is included in Spring Core, so I need to create the Flyway Bean programatically.

```
@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
Flyway flyway() {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
    flyway.setDataSource(baseUrl, username, password);
    return flyway;
}
```

The problem is how to do that **in Tests**? I would like to **run the tests against the in-memmory database,** so I include teh application.yml in test/resources. But then the Flyway bean is not found. When I remove application.yml from test/resources, then it runs fine, but the properties are read from application.yml from main/resources. I tried to change the test not to be @SpringBootTest, I can create the Flyway bean manually, but after putting the @TestConfiguration I need to create all the beans manually, not just Flyway. Ho to do it, just to create Flyway bean manually and all the rest leave to Spring Injection?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class SomeTest {
  @Autowired
  private SomeService someService;
  @Test
  public void test(){
    String helloString = someService.hello();
}}
```

The demo project can be found here: https://github.com/troger19/demo.git

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `flyway-test-extensions` which is a library from Flyway designed to allow testing in Spring against Flyway-managed DBs,

You can have a look at the project's doc [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions), along with some usage examples.

Comment: I dont understand how this can help..I just need to run Flyway against the in-memmory databse, but becasue of defying Flyway programatically (because of old version 4.2.0) and by setting the values from application.properties, I cant change them in SpringBootTest. If I define the @Configuration annotation, I need to create other beans as well, if I create applicatino.properties in test/resource, Flyway  Bean is not created at all.